# SQL connection not available on websphere 6.1 (spring/hibernate/oracle)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring, websphere, connection-pooling

When our application starts up it can't seem to connect to the database (using JNDI) on websphere 6.1.

There are no errors in the logs until hibernate initializes the connection provider; it hangs for 180 seconds (I'm guessing this is the connection timeout set on the datasource) and then:

```
[2011-08-19 10:48:27,585] INFO  [SoapConnectorThreadPool : 1] [o.h.c.ConnectionProviderFactory] Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider µ
[2011-08-19 10:51:27,628] DEBUG [SoapConnectorThreadPool : 1] [o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Exception com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 180029
            at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1362) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar:na]
            at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:462) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar:na]
            at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:418) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:113) [hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863) [hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859) [hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870) [hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860) [spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779) [spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211) [spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE] :
```

The database itself is fine (we can connect to it using a db tool) and the same application does work at times without changing any code or configuration. Also, on our local WAS the application runs without issues but here we do use a different oracle.

Any hint or thoughts on the issue are more than welcome.

**UPDATE:**
After further investigation it seems that the above error is because there are no more connections available in the pool. I don't know if there is a problem with our code (I would expect Hibernate handles this) or configuration or is there a problem in the websphere setup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

In the end it was a problem with the pool running out of connections; an application (war) inside the ear was missing the Spring's `<tx:annotation-driven ... />` from its context hence a new connection was created for each call to the DB. Adding this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Websphere you can do a "`test connection`" when you set up the datasource. Does that work?
Also is the ojdbc4.jar on the classpath? visible on admin console -> jdbc providers. And make sure the parameter for this entry is correct (environment -> websphere variables)

Comment: Tx. The "test connection" works fine and the ojdbc5.jar is on the classpath.

Comment: May be something utterly stupid but have you checked the version of the ojdbc.jar is working correctly with websphere? I have heard stories of mismatches of ojdbc.jar and certain websphere fixpacks. The timeout really makes me think there is a jar clash somewhere, Websphere is always the usual suspect for me in cases like this, but could also be hibernate/spring.

Comment: @Jerry: the jar is fine, after further investigation it seems there are no more connections available in the pool because the connections never get closed. As far as we know our code/configuration is fine but we'll look into that further. Do you perhaps now this is a websphere configuration?

Comment: From your question I understood that the connection to the database is never made, and that it hangs on hibernate's initialization. The 180 seconds waittime supports this at this is the default timeout for a database connection (datasources -> connection pool properties, here you can also increase the initial and max poolsize). Are you able to switch database on the environment? If the app is running on other environments, there is obviously no big mistake in the code, a clean install and restart of the server should at least show some database activity if your poolsize hypothese turns true.

Comment: it was indeed a problem with the pool running out of connections; an application (war) inside the ear was missing the Spring's <tx:annotation-driven ... /> from its context hence a new connection was created for each call to the DB. Adding this solved the problem. Tx for your help anyway.